# vsftpd not working with data logger

Tags: vsftpd

I've got a data logger from Logic Beach "Intellilogger" that I will be using for a solar energy project. It has FTP capabilities. I have made a dummy data logger function that records date, time, and internal CPU temp.

On the Pi side, I've set up a vsftpd server. I chose a directory /home/pi/ftp to have write access. When I test my ftp connection through FileZilla, everything works fine. I can read/write to the directory. After configuring the data logger with the same connection details it doesn't work.

I spoke with an engineer at the manufacturer and sent him the log files, this is what he replied:

> The logger is getting the following when attempting to connect to the
> server: 
> "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u3"  which is not a
> valid response.
>
> The logger is expecting a 220 FTP response, something
> like: 
> "220-Cerberus FTP Server - Home Edition"

Manual to device: (choose the third option)
http://www.logicbeach.com/manuals/

Can anyone help? It sounds like the RPI FTP isn't compatible. Can I change this 220 FTP response to this valid text? Will changing to another FTP server help?

Comment: compare logger connection options with the filezilla options (e.g. sftp, ftp, ftps, scp, and so on). Look at the port, the username, password and everything.... However it works in FZ for your configs, be sure that matches with the intellilogger connection options. Tell me where to find the manual for your version of the device and I'll read up on it some to help more. What do you have connected to that on the IO side again? Is it multiple or just one solar device(s)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. I've currently set a dummy function on the data logger as to not have to master the IO side yet. Currently it records the date, time, and internal cpu temp. I've gone over the intellilogger connections multiple times, even with the engineer, and they seem fine.

Comment: I think he's saying it's trying to connect via SSH as in SFTP as it's expecting an FTP 220 or maybe SSL as in FTPS. Perhaps the VSFTP needs to allow SSH FTP to work or you need to tell the data logger to connect via regular/insecure FTP or SSL FTP as in FTPS rather than SSH FTP as in SFTP.  That's what it sounds like based on the response I think at least.

Comment: If you have Team Viewer or something and want me to connect to watch or test with you, just let me know. Might just be a buggy client issue as in a bug with the version of the client you are using to connect to the server which doesn't exist in the version of Filezilla or some other client that does work.